# LibGDX, how i get loudness level my voice?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I would like to get loudness level for example my voice (on live for each frame) in my game. When game detect medium level loudness hero should jump, in high level hero should jump higher. How Can I do my idea?

edit
I have not idea how to fix the problem. I think that this part of code can help, but i don't know how to implement this to solve my problem. I can't use classes MediaRecorder or AudioRecord, because I do not have access in LibGDX to android libraries.

```
 short buffer[] = new short[bufferSize];
    read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    double p2 = data[data.length-1];
    double decibel;
    if (p2==0)
        decibel=Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    else
        decibel = 20.0*Math.log10(p2/65535.0);
```

My player update method for each frame:

```
 public void update(float differenceFrames)
        {
            if(position.y > 0 )
    velocity.add(0,GRAVITY,0);
    velocity.scl(differenceFrames);
    position.add(MOVEMENT * differenceFrames,velocity.y, 0);
    if(position.y < 0)
        position.y = 0;
    velocity.scl(1/differenceFrames);
    bounds.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        }




     public void jump()
            {
        velocity.y = 175;
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide what have you done? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for reply.